# Uninstalling chef-client

Tags: linux, chef-infra

I'm trying to setup a chef server and workstation in Linux environment( RHEL 6.5). I have used chef-server version 11.0.10 . While setting up chef workstation I installed version 12.3.

Since I'm facing issues while executing knife configure command, I'm trying to uninstall the chef-client and install version 11.0.0.

I executed the below commands to uninstall chef-client:

```
rpm -qa \*chef\*  
yum remove <package>
```

When I tried to install chef-client 11.0.0, I get error as below:

```
from package chef-12.3.0-1.el6.x86_64
    file /opt/chef/embedded/share/terminfo/x/xnuppc-144x48 from install of chef-11.0.0-1.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package chef-12.3.0-1.el6.x86_64
    file /opt/chef/embedded/share/terminfo/x/xnuppc-144x48-m from install of chef-11.0.0-1.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package chef-12.3.0-1.el6.x86_64
    file /opt/chef/embedded/share/terminfo/x/xnuppc-160x64 from install of chef-11.0.0-1.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package chef-12.3.0-1.el6.x86_64

  file /opt/chef/embedded/ssl/misc/c_info from install of chef-11.0.0-1.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package chef-12.3.0-1.el6.x86_64
    file /opt/chef/embedded/ssl/misc/c_issuer from install of chef-11.0.0-1.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package chef-12.3.0-1.el6.x86_64
    file /opt/chef/embedded/ssl/misc/c_name from install of chef-11.0.0-1.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package chef-12.3.0-1.el6.x86_64
    file /opt/chef/embedded/ssl/misc/tsget from install of chef-11.0.0-1.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package chef-12.3.0-1.el6.x86_64
    file /opt/chef/embedded/ssl/openssl.cnf from install of chef-11.0.0-1.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package chef-12.3.0-1.el6.x86_64
    file /opt/chef/version-manifest.txt from install of chef-11.0.0-1.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package chef-12.3.0-1.el6.x86_64
```

Any suggestions to resolve the issue is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have ruby and rubygems installed on your machine? If yes you can run `gem uninstall chef -v <version>`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a rpm-specialist, but it seems another version of the package (12.3.0) is installed.

Checking if it's true, and why it is installed, may yield you to the problem.

Comment: I had installed 12.3.0 version of package. But I uninstalled it . Still I get this error.

Comment: I was able to uninstall version 12.3.0 using the command: > yum erase chef

Answer (score 0):

I was able to completely remove chef packages using -e flag.

Try :

```
rpm -e packagename
```